# How to write a custom serializer by using DataContractSerializer for generic type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, azure

I want to write a custom serializer for storing the session state into **Azure Cache (Preview)**, so that means this custom serializer has to implement `IDataCacheObjectSerializer` (*if I am wrong, please let me know*). The reason why I need to write this custome serializer is i need to serialize some Linq objects which contain some `System.Data.Linq.EntitySet` attributes. And the default serializer `NetDataContractSerializer` cannot serialize the `EntitySet`.

My plan is to write a custom serializer by using `DataContractSerializer` (*I searched some articles that mentioned `DataContractSerializer` can serialize `EntitySet`, so if I am wrong, let me know please*), but the problem is how I can write a custom serializer that can support generic type.

Currently, my codes for custom serializer are like:

```
public class CustomSerializer : IDataCacheObjectSerializer
{
    public CustomSerializer()
    { }
    public object Deserialize(System.IO.Stream stream)
    {
        /* How can I know the type of object?????? */
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer("Type of object");
    }

    public void Serialize(System.IO.Stream stream, object value)
    {
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(value.GetType());
        dcs.WriteObject(stream, value);
    }
}
```

By the way, I have changed the Linq Serialization Mode to "Unidirectional"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not work with IDataCacheObjectSerializer, but common solution looks like this:

```
public sealed class CustomSerializer<T> : IDataCacheObjectSerializer
{
    object IDataCacheObjectSerializer.Deserialize(System.IO.Stream stream)
    {       
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        return dcs.ReadObject(stream);
    }

    void IDataCacheObjectSerializer.Serialize(System.IO.Stream stream, object value)
    {
        if (!(value is T)) 
        {
            throw new AgrumentException();
        }
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        dcs.WriteObject(stream, value);
    }
}
```