# How can I store Linq to Sql objects in session using Windows Azure Cache Service (Preview)

Tags: c#, linq, session, caching, azure

I'd like to take advantage of the new Windows Azure Cache Service (Preview) and was able to successfully store in and retrieve things from the cache using Session by following [this article](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cache/net/how-to-cache-service/#getting-started-cache-service). Unfortunately we are storing Linq to Sql objects in Session and we are not able to change that at this point. When attempting to store such objects in Session using the Azure Cache Service, I get the following error:

> *Type 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1[cachetest.Child]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.*

I used the "Unidirectional" Serialization Mode for my data context, so all declarations are already decorated with "DataContract" and "DataMember" attributes (see code sample below).

I've looked into using a Custom Serializer [similar to this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh552969.aspx) and [this article on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707939/how-to-write-a-custom-serializer-by-using-datacontractserializer-for-generic-typ), but received an error that matched the exact error described towards the end [of this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx), in which it is stated that

> the ASP.NET providers for Cache do not support binary or custom serialization types

Since a custom serializer is not an option, how else can I store Linq to Sql objects (with parent-child relationships) in Session using Windows Azure Caching?

I've broken out the code that illustrates the issue below.
The Linq DataContext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Database Class="TestModelDataContext" Serialization="Unidirectional" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/linqtosql/dbml/2007">
  <Table Name="" Member="Parents">
    <Type Name="Parent">
      <Column Member="Name" Type="System.String" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Member="ParentId" Type="System.Int32" IsPrimaryKey="true" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Association Name="Parent_Child" Member="Childs" ThisKey="ParentId" OtherKey="ParentId" Type="Child" />
    </Type>
  </Table>
  <Table Name="" Member="Childs">
    <Type Name="Child">
      <Column Member="Name" Type="System.String" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Member="ChildId" Type="System.Int32" IsPrimaryKey="true" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Member="ParentId" Type="System.Int32" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Association Name="Parent_Child" Member="Parent" ThisKey="ParentId" OtherKey="ParentId" Type="Parent" IsForeignKey="true" />
    </Type>
  </Table>
</Database>
```

Page using the session:

```
namespace cachetest
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Parent newParent = new Parent { Name = "John", ParentId=1 };
        Child child1 = new Child { ChildId = 1, Name="John Jr." };
        Child child2 = new Child { ChildId = 2, Name="Betty" };
        newParent.Childs.Add(child1);
        newParent.Childs.Add(child2);
        Session["parent"] = newParent;

    }
}
```

}
Web.Config (sensitive data removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dataCacheClients" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientsSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
    <section name="cacheDiagnostics" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon.DiagnosticsConfigurationSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime/>    
    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AFCacheSessionStateProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="AFCacheSessionStateProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="default" dataCacheClientName="default" applicationName="AFCacheSessionState"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="default">
      <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="[cachename].cache.windows.net"/>
      <securityProperties mode="Message" sslEnabled="false">
        <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="[CacheKey]"/>
      </securityProperties>
    </dataCacheClient>
  </dataCacheClients>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Better this than two sentences and no research!

Comment: @gunr2171 Thanks for taking a look! The majority of the code was autogenerated by the linq to sql datacontext so I replaced it with the Xml, much shorter!

Comment: @HitsKeys I am stuck with same exact error. Can you tell me if you were able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @Tromax I posted my answer, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

After more research I was unable to find a way to store Linq to Sql objects in session while using Windows Azure Caching Service. I ran into the same issue with other out of process session mechanisms like SQL Server based session state. The best solution for me was to use a SessionHelper object similar to [the one in this article](http://www.squaredroot.com/2008/01/30/storing-linq-objects-in-sql-based-session-state/). I changed the line in Page Load where the object is stored into the Session to:

```
SessionHelper.Set("Parent", newParent);
```

In the end, my problem was not specifically related to Windows Azure caching, but very similar to [this article on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643793/are-linq-to-sql-objects-serializable-for-session-state)